# Cannot record microphone with SimpleScreenRecorder

Tags: audio, pulseaudio, recording, kde-neon

As mentioned in the title, I'm unable to simultaneously record my headset microphone *and* my desktop audio when using SimpleScreenRecorder in KDE Neon 5.24.

In the "Audio Input" section of the recording settings, I selected "PulseAudio" as **Backend**, whereas for **Source** I've tried both "Built-in Audio Analog Stereo" as well as "Monitor of Built-in Audio Analog Stereo" (see below):

[image]

When selecting "Built-in Audio Analog Stereo", the microphone gets recorded but the desktop audio does not, while the situation is exactly the opposite when I select "Monitor of Built-in Audio Analog Stereo" (can record desktop audio but not headset microphone).

Does anybody have an idea of how to solve this issue?

Comment: Do you use pulseaudio or pipewire? You could create a virtual audio device where you mix the different inputs.

Comment: Note: you could also use OBS, which allows for more complex scenarios

Comment: @mashuptwice I've got pulseaudio. How do I create a virtual audio device? Feel free to expand your document into a full-blown answer if needed.
Regarding OBS, I'm not sure I need all those features, but I'll try it if nothing else works.

Comment: I have the same issue recently. Monitor worked before but it doesn't work now. It didn't require any setting or the JACK installation described in the answer section below. Have you solved this issue?

Comment: @JonathanTse I have solved by switching to vokoscreenNG, which has fewer features than SimpleScreenRecorder but at least doesn't have that issue. Haven't tried following the instructions in the answer below though

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, and I will explain how I made it work in my system step by step. I hope this can help someone else.

I will leave the links to some websites that were very useful.

The global idea is to install JACK to manage the audio, and bridge JACK to Pulseaudio to be able to control the audio volume.

Step1. Remove Pulseaudio from the system to get a clean JACK installation:

```
sudo apt-get remove pulseaudio 
sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove pulseaudio 
sudo apt-get purge pulseaudio
```

Step 2. Install JACK:

```
sudo apt-get install qjackctl jackd2
```

These are:
qjackctl/stable,stable 0.9.1-1 amd64, the user interface for controlling the JACK sound server
jackd2/stable,stable 1.9.17~dfsg-1 amd64, JACK Audio Connection Kit (server and example clients)
During JACK installation, a windows open asking to Enable realtime process priority. I answered yes.
[image]

Step3. Once installed, execute JACK, and a graphical interface will open
[image]

Step4. Re-install Pulseaudio and module-jack

```
sudo apt-get install pulseaudio-module-jack
sudo apt-get install pulseaudio
```

Step5. Install Cadence software to allow bridging Pulseaudio/ALSA with JACK

```
sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https gpgv
wget https://launchpad.net/~kxstudio-debian/+archive/kxstudio/+files/kxstudio-repos_10.0.3_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i kxstudio-repos_10.0.3_all.deb
sudo apt install cadence
```

Step6. Configure the system. Here is where you will need to play around depending on your system audio devices.
On JACK, open settings (Setup...), and define your sound card. These are mine:[image]

[image]

Execute Cadence:
Bridge ALSA/Pulseaudio with JACK
[image]

Restart the system
Step 7. Configure Simplescreenrecoder to listen to your device. Check that it is getting audio from the system and microphone
[image]

Probably this will not work at the first time. Play around with the JACK and Cadence configuration.

Some links that helped me:
https://www.thelinuxfaq.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-17-04-zesty-zapus/pulseaudio?type=uninstall
https://www.maartenbaert.be/simplescreenrecorder/recording-game-audio/#recording-game-audio-and-microphone-at-the-same-time

If you need something different, or I missed a step, please comment. This is not easy, and having clear steps would help so many people.

Good luck everyone

Comment: This solves for me, but had some issues, [cadence to work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1231848/cadence-has-no-installation-candidate-in-ubuntu-mate-20-04) and [Sound test to work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1392396/sound-works-but-testing-speakers-does-not-work-anymore-ubuntu-20-04)

Answer (score 0):

I'm using PulseAudio on Ubuntu 20.04, and for me, it was just a matter of selecting the right audio device. This may depend on your hardware.